# R macro: how to f(x) --> g("x")

Tags: r, macros, stringify

How can I use defmacro (from gtools) to arrange it so that when I type `f(x)` the result is the return value of `g("x")` ?

I suppose (because I am a C programmer) that defmacro is involved... but I would be happy to achieve the goal with or without defmacro.

Unfortunately `f <- defmacro(x, expr={ g(quote(x)) })` is hit and miss... it works for some functions, but fails for others, like for example

```
g <- function(v) {
  eval(parse(text=paste0("f0 = lm(Sale_Price ~ ", v, ", data = d1)")))
  r0 <- data.frame(predict(f0, d1), d1$Sale_Price)
  colnames(r0) <- c(v, "Sale_Price")
  ggplot() +
  labs(x= v, y= "Sale_Price") +
  geom_point(data = r0, aes(get(v), Sale_Price), colour="black") +
  geom_smooth(data = r0, method = "lm", aes(x = get(v), y Sale_Price), colour="blue", se = FALSE)
}
```

I can modify the above definition so that
`f <- defmacro(x, expr={ g(quote(x)) })` will succeed... but that is not my question.  I want to know how *in general* it can be arranged so that when I type `f(x)` the result is the return value of `g("x")` for *arbitrary* user-defined `g` (but I would appreciate an answer which works with mild restrictions on `g`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I type `f(x)` the result is the return value of `g("x")` for
>   arbitrary user-defined `g`

```
f <- function(x, g) {
  g(as.character(substitute(x)))
} 

#using paste as an example of g    
f(a, paste)
#[1] "a"
```

Do not use `eval(parse())`. Forget it exists until you are much more advanced in your knowledge of the language. You can do something like this:

```
form <- as.formula(sprintf("Sale_Price ~ %s", v))
f0 <- lm(form, data = d1)
```

Also, study `help("aes_string")`. You don't need `get`.